# Bash command to copy a log file to another directory as soon as specified expression is found in it

Tags: bash, grep, xargs, tail, cp

I've got a log file that is rotated automatically when it reaches a certain size. The system keeps 5 rotated logs at a time, the older ones are deleted, and the lifetime of a log file is about 20 minutes.

The task is to monitor the log file (system.log) for a specified error code and when it occurs – to copy the file into another directory, before it is deleted.

I tried this:

```
tail -F system.log | grep -l "error code" | xargs cp /another/directory
```

but it returns "cp: taget 'input)' is not a directory"

Apparently this is because grep command does not return the file name as soon as the error code is found in it as I expected.

So I need some help here please.

Comment: I think Barmar's `-T` is the better solution, but another alternative is `xargs -i` with explicit an placeholder - `tail -F system.log | grep -l "error code" | xargs -i cp {} /another/directory`

Comment: I tried this tail -F system.log | grep -l "error code" | xargs -i cp {} /another/directory
and it returned 'cp: cannot stat '(standard input)': no such file or directory'
It seems that something is wrong with the part tail -F system.log | grep -l "error code"
as it returns (standard input) instead of the name of the file

Answer (score 2):

The normal order of arguments to `cp` is

```
cp source destination
```

`xargs` puts its arguments at the end of the command, so you're executing the command

```
cp /another/directory input
```

which has to arguments backwards.

To solve this, use the `-t` option to `cp` to specify the destination explicitly.

```
xargs cp -t /another/directory
```

Comment: I tried this: 'tail -F system.log | grep -l "error code" | xargs cp -T /another/directory'
and it returns "cp: extra operand 'input)'"

Comment: Is it because xargs puts its arguments at the end of the command as you said? 
If so, how can I change it?

Comment: Sorry, it's `-t`, not `-T`, as you surely could have figured out yourself by reading the man page.

Comment: Why are you using `grep -l`? There's no filename when you pipe to `grep`. So it prints `(standard input)` and tries to copy files named `(standard` and `input)` to the destination directory.

Comment: You need to use something like `if grep -q "error code" system.log; then cp "system.log" /another/directory"; fi`

Comment: That's it. I've just added a loop so that it monitor the file for the expression to appear in it:

`i=1
while(( 1<2 ))
do if grep -q "error code" system.log; then cp system.log /another/directory; break; else continue; fi; done`

it does exactly what I need.
Thank you

Comment: Another way to do it:
`while [ "$searchError" = "" ] do  searchError='grep "error code" system.log' done 
cp system.log /another/directory;`

Comment: @GriM Except the `grep` command should be inside `$(...)`, not quotes.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried this tail -F system.log | grep -l "error code" | xargs -i cp {} /another/directory and it returned 'cp: cannot stat '(standard input)': no such file or directory' It seems that something is wrong with the part tail -F system.log | grep -l "error code" as it returns (standard input) instead of the name of the file

*Oops.* I can't believe I didn't see that before...

```
$: echo foo | grep -l foo
(standard input)
```

`tail` is sending the file to `grep`, so `grep`'s file ***IS*** stdin, so that's what it's listing.

## edit

Are you using `logrotate`?
Check out [the manual](https://linuxconfig.org/logrotate-8-manual-page) and look carefully at the `prerotate`/`postrotate`/`firstaction`/`lastaction` options.

For an example, Option 7 [here](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/07/logrotate-examples/) -
have your script scan the just-rotated log, and if it has the trigger string in it, copy it somewhere.